# How to properly display two strings side by side

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, string

I have two arrays which I use implode() on to convert into strings which are then echoed out.

Ideally i'd like the 1 value from the one string to be next to the other value in the other string, prefably nested inside a

```
<p></p>
```

Here's the code I'm using to issue a line break after every value, wrap it in a div, and float it.

```
<?php 
echo '<div class="wrapper"><div style="text-align:left; float:left;"         
class="glue">';
echo implode('<br>',$test);
echo '</div>';
echo '<div style="text-align:right; float:right;" class="glue">';
echo implode('<br>',$_POST);
echo '</div></div>';
?>
```

This works well for now as both divs sit next to each other within my container but it would be easier if the values were inside P tags instead so I could easily put an image in-between them.

I've added some images below to better demonstrate what I'm going for.
The first one is what I've tried and the second one is what I would like.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Simply use `float:left` for both the inner `div`

Comment: That would still produce the same result, I don't want each column of numbers to be in seperate divs, I want the the first value of each to be in a <p></p> same for the second and so on, is it doable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
<style type="text/css">
    p{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    span.left{
        float: left;
    }
    span.right{
        float: right;
    }
</style>
<?php
foreach($test as $k=>$v){
    echo '<p><span class="left">'.$test[$k].'</span><span class="right">'.$_POST[$k].'</span></p>';
}
```

Comment: Yes! How do I do that in php? Whenever I try and wrap them in a <p> it only does one number at a time

Comment: May be like that?

`<style type="text/css">
    p{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    span.left{
        float: left;
    }
    span.right{
        float: right;
    }
</style>
<?php
foreach($test as $k=>$v){
 echo '<p><span class="left">'.$test[$k].'</span><span class="right">'.$_POST[$k].'</span></p>';
}
?>`

Comment: You're the man! Add your comment to your answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: I have changed the answer

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible until you split the paragraph tag into 2 halves.

Try this,

```css
.div1 {
    float: left;
}

.div2 {
    float:right;
}

.div2 {
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <div class="div1">Left Text</div>
    <div class="div2">Right Text</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

if both arrays have the same length the most simple example woud look like this:

```
<?php 
$test[0] = "a";
$test[1] = "b";
$test[2] = "c";
$test[3] = "d";
$test2[0] = 1;
$test2[1] = 2;
$test2[2] = 3;
$test2[3] = 4;
for($i=0;$i<count($test);$i++)
{
echo "<p><nobr>".$test[$i] . "</nobr> <nobr style='float:right;'>" . $test2[$i] . "</nobr></p>";
}
```

if you wanna test to see if it fits just paste the code [here](http://phptester.net/)

Comment: I think this bit of code works well, <?php echo '<p>'.$test[0]; ?> <?php echo $_POST[0].'</p>'; ?>
But it only display the first value from each, but the output is what I want, is there a way to go through arrays starting from 0 like you did with for($i=0;$i<count($test);$i++)

Comment: yes, for($i=0;$i<count($test);$i++) actually does exactly what you want. it counts the variable $i from 0 to the last index of your array ($test) and you only have to add your code between the brackets({ }) and change your index to $i ($test[$i]).